# Beeping sound from nowhere... probably error

Tags: c#, loops, console, beep

This is one of the biggest weird things I've ever seen
There is a code for searching all elements in List q variable

```
    public List<String> SearchQuestion(String fromPart)
    {
        return q.FindAll(r => r.Contains(fromPart));
    }
```

And there is how I use it in main

```
foreach (String s in GameMaster.SearchQuestion("a"))
     Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Program is working, it's not crash at all, but I am using headset and my ears almost exploded by that (yup it's not motherboard beeper fault)

What's wrong with this code? What does that 4 beeps mean?

Comment: Is any character you're printing to the console ASCII character 7? That'll make it beep for every single 0x07 character.

Comment: " … " (w/o quotes)
Case solved, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely it means that (String) `s` contains 4 characters that are interpreted as a system "bell"  character.

Old school ASCII encoding for the Bell character was `0x07`.

So in Unicode, we'd expect the beep to be caused by writing character U+0007 to the console. (There may be other Unicode characters that are also interpreted equivalent to the "bell" character.)

Comment: How to make if statement to check if current character in string is 0x07 or U+0007? I've made a lot of copy paste strings from some website, maybe this is a reason?

Comment: Ok I've got it, its: " … " (w/o quotes). Thanks :)